# How do I allow a user to install multiple versions of my software simultaneously?

Tags: inno-setup

I'm setting up a Windows installer for a new software product using InnoSetup. The tool completes engineering calculations and future versions will contain improved algorithms or functionality. Most users will want to keep the old version even when they install a new version so they can reproduce results for old projects.

Can I make InnoSetup install a new version alongside the old version?

I've tried putting the software version number in the default directory name:

```
DefaultDirName={pf}\{#PRODUCT_NAME} {#PRODUCT_VERSION_LONG}
```

and forcing folder selection:

```
DisableDirPage=yes
```

The first installation works fine, but when the installer is run for a later version, it sees the first version is installed and pulls in the first version folder name as the default location - so version 0.2 installs in the " 0.1" folder.

The only workaround I can think of is to generate a new AppId for each version - effectively making every version a new software product. Is there a better way?